# why cant i change my page name without documentation to prove name change?

Tags: facebook

I have a page on facebook which showcases my art work and so people can see the art work I am able to do.

I set this page up in 2009 and since then I have developed my style and I wish to change the name of this page and rebrand it.

However, when I have requested the change on facebook I am being told I cannot do this without documentation to prove the name change. This is not a business, it is just a personal page so I have no docuemtnation!

Please can you inform me as soon as possible as to how I can change the page name? With this being a personal page, there is no reason as to why I shouldnt be able to change this myself, I should not need to ask permission to do so.

Regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Or You Can Still Use The Method Below Though Still Require Documentation.

The process for changing your Facebook Page name is as follows: 
1. Go to your Admin Panel 
2. Select Edit Page then Update Public Info 
3. In the Basic Info section go to Name about half way down the Page 
4. If less than 200 Likes change Edit the name in the Name field 
5. If more than 200 Likes select the Request Change link 6. Check the ‘I understand the formatting guidelines for my Page’s new name’ box 
7. Select the appropriate option under ‘Your Page name currently represents’ 
8. Check the ‘I would still like to change my Page name. I have documentation to demonstrate this change’ box 
9. Enter ‘Your Desired Page Name’ 
10. Enter the reason for the name change from the drop down 
11. Upload appropriate documentation such as a utility bill or phone bill.

Facebook will then let you know if your request has been approved; hopefully within a few days. If you have any questions on your Facebook Page please use the Ask a Question flyout on the left.